# Java2WSDL (Axis) Class Not Found

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I have added the following to System Variables

- %AXIS_LIB%\axis.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\commons-discovery.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\commons-logging.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\jaxrpc.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\saaj.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\log4j-1.2.8.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\xml-apis.jar
- %AXIS_LIB%\xercesImpl.jar

I have %AXIS_LIB% defined as c:\Axis-1_4\lib.

Following the tutorial, I tried to use Java2WSDL to produce the WSDL file.

```
% java org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL -o wp.wsdl
    -l"http://localhost:8080/axis/services/WidgetPrice"
    -n  "urn:Example6" -p"samples.userguide.example6" "urn:Example6"
    samples.userguide.example6.WidgetPrice
```

However, I am getting a Class Not Found error.

```
C:\axis-1_4\samples\userguide\example6>java org.apache.axis.
wsdl.Java2WSDL -o wp.wsdl -l "http://localhost:8080/axis/services/WidgetPrice" -
n "urn:Example6" -p "samples.userguide.example6" "urn:Example6" samples.userguid
e.example6.WidgetPrice
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/wsdl/
Java2WSDL
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL.  Program will exi
t.
```

Why am I not able to invoke Java2WSDL?

Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding , Was all required jars in ClassPath? can use the above command as java -cp and the remaining required ?

Comment: I added the -CP command with the Classpath variable. Now it is giving me a different error. Something like commmons-logging class not found. What's weird is that I have added the commons-logging.jar into the classpath.

Comment: I think so u havent added jars on to your classpath ,please set the jars class path exactly, the cause may be for NoClassDefFoundError is [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) please verify it, Set all  required to the CLASSPATH environment variable and use it execution of time as %CLASSPATH% same it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to make `AXIS_LIB` available in the class path otherwise Java will not be able to find `org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL`; You can do this either by setting `CLASSPATH` to `%AXIS_LIB%;%CLASSPATH%` or by adding `-cp %AXIS_LIB%` to your command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I set the classpaths and made sure the environment variables were correct. It works now!

Comment: I am facing the same error on my MAC, the environment, classpath everything looks correct. But still I am getting the error